# When can I unlock Ultimate difficulty?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In *NEO: The World Ends with You*, how far do I need to progress in the story to unlock Ultimate difficulty? I tried searching myself, but stopped after the first article I opened revealed late-game spoilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into spoilers, it can be unlocked in the post-game after purchasing it in the Social Network. So you'll have to beat the game and get into the post game content.

Comment: Do I need to do any side quests, or does the social link unlock right after beating the game?

Comment: The person in question becomes available with no sidequest needed.